# ecto fragment as query source

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT days.date, SUM(tes.duration) FROM (
  SELECT 
      DATE_FORMAT(
          now() - INTERVAL (@num := @num + 1) DAY,
          '%Y-%m-%d'
      ) date
  FROM time_entries, (SELECT @num:=-1) num
  LIMIT 31
) AS days
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT te.duration, DATE_FORMAT(te.date, '%Y-%m-%d') date
  FROM time_entries AS te
  WHERE te.account_id = 50150 AND te.deleted_at IS NULL
) AS tes ON tes.date = days.date
GROUP BY days.date
ORDER BY days.date
```

But this does not seem possible in ecto. I'm attempting this:

```
from(
  # creates 30 rows for each date 30 days into the past
  days in subquery(
    from(
      num in "time_entries, (SELECT @num := -1)",
      select: %{
        date: fragment("DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL (@num := @num + 1) DAY, '%Y-%m-%d')")
      }
    )
  ),
  # join each date with time entries on this account and sub duration for each day
  left_join: tes in subquery(
    from(
      # using time_entries__undeleted was really slow for some reason… need to look into that
      te in "time_entries",
      select: %{
        duration: te.duration,
        date: fragment("DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%d')", te.date),
        where: te.account_id == ^user.account_id
      },
    )
  ), on: tes.date == days.date,
  group_by: days.date,
  order_by: days.date
)
```

But i get the error:

```
(Mariaex.Error) (1146): Table 'development.time_entries, (select @num := -1)' doesn't exist
```

I need to compose dynamically on top of this query so I would like to not resort to `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this that way, however syntax `SELECT … FROM a, b …` is rough equivalent to `SELECT … FROM a CROSS JOIN b …` which is supported by Ecto. So what you need is

```
from entry in "time_entries",
  cross_join: num in fragment("(SELECT @num = -1)"),
  …
```

Comment: YES! this is the answer I've been agonizing to find. Thank you so much! Works brilliantly